# Testing an application that makes use of threads in wxwidgets

Tags: c++, multithreading, testing, wxwidgets

I have a project at :-
visit http://wxwidgetsthreadsafety.blogspot.in/ ,
the project says that a thread is incrementing the value of counter till it reaches the 0xFFFFFFFF and anothere thread main() which is displaying the value ,although i have made use of critical sections , i need to know how do i test it , i mean i want to run multiple threads say 10 threads and test.

I am using wxwidgets-2.8.12 and netbeans 7.1.1
Please add the code if any .

Thanks

Comment: You have described the main thread displaying the value, and one thread  to increment the value.  What do the other 8 threads do?

Comment: Ok, what i meant was if there are 10 instances of a single thread running in a second and all want to access the same critical section or youmay correct me .

Comment: So, do all these threads want to update the value, display it, or what?

Comment: Well i have got two critical sections one that takes care of the update and another for display so one can consider like no two threads should print the same value at a single time.

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete and overly broad. It cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. 1 vote to close.

Comment: ok,let me mae it more clear what i am asking as i mentioned i have two threads ,when i run this code the first thread(main) outputs the counter value when it outputs the counter value i make this thread sleep for 1 second and on the output screen/window i don't want another instance of the thread (output the counter value)to output the counter value .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10579/discussion-between-kimi-houston-and-ravenspoint)